# Unusual Syntax Error in PyGame using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, syntax, import

```
import pygame
import time
import random
from __builtin__ import quit

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

red = (200,0,0)
green = (0,200,0)

bright_red = (255,0,0)
bright_green = (0,255,0)

ship_width = 73

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Galaxia Remastered')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

background = pygame.image.load('space1.png')
background = pygame.transform.scale(background, (800,600))

shipImg = pygame.image.load('ship1.png')
shipImg = pygame.transform.scale(shipImg, (73,73))

mobImg = pygame.image.load('ufo.png')
mobImg = pygame.transform.scale(mobImg, (100,100))

def mobs_dodged(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render("Dodged: "+str(count), True, white)
    gameDisplay.blit(text,(0,0))

def mobs(mobx, moby, mobw, mobh):
    gameDisplay.blit(mobImg,(mobx,moby))

def ship(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(shipImg,(x,y))

def text_objects(text,font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, white)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text,font)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf,TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

    time.sleep(2)

    game_loop()

def crash():
    message_display('You Crashed!')

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac, (x,y,w,h))
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,ic, (x,y,w,h))
    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, font)
    textRect.center = ((x+(w/2)),(y+(h/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)
```

The last line gives me an invalid syntax error, highlighting the "gameDisplay". After looking around myself, there was an "import gameDisplay from..." another file I had within the project. I thought that it would be fixed if I deleted the line, however it stated "unresolved import". I restarted Ecplise and cleaned my project multiple times but it still doesn't work. I sent the program to my other computer and it still gets the same error. When I remove the "gameDisplay" line, it tells me that there is an invalid syntax in "def game_intro():".

All help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Haven't ran your code but it looks like there are some mismatched parentheses on your second to last line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you got one mismatched paranthese on line 74
Just remove the very first one on that line and your code should work just fine again..

```
textRect.center = (x+(w/2)),(y+(h/2))
```